# MQ error code 2058 when connecting to queue manager by name

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm experiencing an odd behavior when running basic connectivity tests from my workstation to a remote MQ Server.

I am using amqssslc.exe to connect from a command prompt.

If I connect with nothing but a certificate store, it connects without issue, and returns a result indicating that it connected to the default queue manager, FOO:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\Tools\c\Samples\Bin64>amqssslc.exe -k c:\mycerts\cert

Sample AMQSSSLC start
Connecting to the default queue manager
No client connection information specified.
Using SSL key repository stem c:\mycerts\cert
No OCSP configuration specified.
Connection established to queue manager FOO
Sample AMQSSSLC end
```

If I attempt to connect to the queue manager FOO, however, it returns a 2058 error, which typically indicates a queue manager name error.

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\Tools\c\Samples\Bin64>amqssslc.exe -k c:\mycerts\cert -m FOO

Sample AMQSSSLC start
Connecting to queue manager FOO
No client connection information specified.
Using SSL key repository stem c:\mycerts\cert
No OCSP configuration specified.
MQCONNX ended with reason code 2058
```

It does this even if I copy the name directly from the result. It fails quickly, and doesn't generate a log entry in my AMQERR01.LOG file.

Does this behavior indicate an issue with my CCDT file?

---

### Update:

Per @JoshMc's suggestion, I ran the following command to get information about the vendor-supplied CCDT file:

```
echo DIS CHL(*) QMNAME CONNAME|runmqsc -n
```

The results indicated that no queue manager was specified in the file:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\Tools\c\Samples\Bin64>echo DIS CHL(*) QMNAME CONNAME|runmqsc -n
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2016.
Starting local MQSC for 'MYQUEUE.TAB'.
 1 : DIS CHL(*) QMNAME CONNAME
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(FOOCHANNEL)                CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN)
   CONNAME(CONNAME(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(1414),xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(1414))
   QMNAME( )

No commands have a syntax error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you review the source code located at `C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\Tools\c\Samples\Bin64\amqssslc.c` you can see that it does the following:

1. If no queue manager name is specified it will set the queue manager name to `NULL` and print `Connecting to the default queue manager`
2. If no connection name is specified it will not setup the `ClientConn`, and `ConnectOptions.ClientConnPtr` is left at it's default `NULL` value, it will print `No client connection information specified.`
3. If a SSL key repository stem is specified it will set the `SslConnOptions.KeyRepository` to this value and print out `Using SSL key repository stem <stem location>` and then point `ConnectOptions.SSLConfigPtr` to the `SslConnOptions`.

After all of this it then issues a `MQCONNX` and specifies the the `NULL` queue manager name and the `ConnectOptions`.  Because the `ConnectOptions.ClientConnPtr` is left at the default `NULL` value MQ will attempt to find the out how to connect to the queue manager via a few different other means.  The order and where it looks for connection information is documented at the IBM v7.5 (or later) Knowledge Center page "[Connecting IBM WebSphere MQ MQI client applications to queue managers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027440_.htm)".  In your case it is picking up the CCDT file.

When you do not specify a queue manager name it looks for a entry in the CCDT with a blank `QMNAME` attribute and finds the `CLNTCONN` channel that you have defined where `QMNAME` is blank.  A blank `QMNAME` on a `CLNTCONN` channel is a special case where the MQ client will connect to any queue manager name which is listening at `CONNAME` that you specify.  Because you are specifying the SSL key repository stem it will use this key repository to connect to MQ with the `SSLCIPH` you have specified on `CLNTCONN` in the CCDT.

When you **do** specify the queue manager name `FOO`, it attempts to find a entry in the CCDT with the `QMNAME` attribute set to `FOO`, in your case it does not exist so you receive the `2058` or `MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR` error.

---

Based on your update the CCDT channel does have a blank `QMNAME` attribute and the `CONNAME` lists two different IP(PORT) seperated by a common.  With this configuration MQ will attempt first to connect to the first IP, if the connection times out or is ended for some other reason such as the channel on the queue manager being in STOPPED status, it will then attempt to connect to the second IP.

It is very possible they intend for you to connect with a blank or NULL queue manager name due to the benefit that the client will connect to any queue manager name that is listening on the CONNAME, in you case the first IP(PORT) might be queue manager FOO and the second IP(PORT) might be queue manager BAR.

---

If you want it to work with your CCDT when you specify `-m FOO` you would need to either create a new CCDT with a `CLNTCONN` channel with `QMNAME(FOO)`, or add another `CLNTCONN` channel to your existing CCDT with `QMNAME(FOO)`, note you can not have duplicate channel names in a single CCDT.

---

For more information on the CCDT and what queue manager name to specify see my answer to "[Connecting to IBM MQ using CCDT file in JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969323/connecting-to-ibm-mq-using-ccdt-file-in-jms/45971106#45971106)".  The answer was related to JMS but the information applies to MQI clients as well.

---

You also have the option to specify all the details on the command line like Roger said.  Run `amqssslc.exe ?` for usage information, it should look like this:

```
Sample AMQSSSLC start
Parameters:  [-m QMgr]
  [-c ChlName -x ConnName]
  [-k KeyReposStem] [-s CipherSpec]
  [-p any|rfc5280]
  [-f] [-b none|128_bit|192_bit[,...] ]
  [-o OcspURL]
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. The CCDT file was provided by a vendor, so I need to wait for a response from them before I can confirm.

Comment: I am using the v9 release. The results I get running the command you suggest return an empty QM name. Does that indicate that the vendor didn't include the needed information in the CCDT file they provided?  

    5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2016.  
    Starting local MQSC for 'MYQUEUE.TAB'.  
         1 : DIS CHL(*) QMNAME CONNAME  
    AMQ8414: Display Channel details.  
       CHANNEL(FOOCHANNEL)                CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN)  
       CONNAME(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(1414),xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(1414))  
       QMNAME( )  
    No commands have a syntax error.

Comment: My apologies for the formatting -- SO doesn't support line breaks in comments.

Comment: Yes, the issue is resolved. I'll mark yours as the answer, and update my question with additional information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @kiprainey, glad that it was helpful.  I based on that the CONNAME contains two IP/Ports then it may very well be that each IP/PORT combination is a different QMNAME, and by specifying blank for this value it allows you to connect to either queue manager.  I'm going to cleanup some old comments above that are covered in your question and my answer.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm experiencing an odd behavior when running basic connectivity tests
>   from my workstation to a remote MQ Server.

Its not the program.  You didn't specify enough parameters.  Did you issue "amqssslc.exe ?" or look at the source? i.e. amqssslc.c

Where is the channel name?  Where is the connection name?  Where is the CipherSpec?  etc...

Comment: One can connect with no parameters at all, e.g. `amqssslc.exe`. The parameters you mention are in the CCDT file.

Comment: After JoshMc explains it to you, you decide to respond with CCDT.  Of course, if you were using a CCDT file then the question becomes 'why didn't you also put the keyrepository in it as well?'.

Comment: On Windows systems, the key repository is often referenced as an environmental variable.