# How to retrieve the connection details From TAB file - MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Can someone please help me to get/read the port number, hostname, channel details when i using ccdt.tab file. these details were configured in tab file. queue creation was opened successfully by using tab file but i want to get above details (connection details) using java.

I can able to get only queue manager name and queue name by using MQQueueSender.getstringproperty(); but other not able to find.

I expect port number, hostname, channel  which i defined in TAB file

```
    MQQueueConnection connection = null;
    MQQueueSession session = null;
    MQQueueSender sender = null;
    MQQueueReceiver receiver = null;
    HashMap<String, String> setValue = null;

    try {

        connection = getConnection(prop.getProperty("tabFilePath"));
        session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MQQueue sendQueue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue(prop.getProperty("queueName"));
        sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(sendQueue);   System.out.println(sender.getStringProperty("XMSC_WMQ_RESOLVED_QUEUE_MANAGER"));
        System.out.println(sender.getStringProperty("XMSC_WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER"));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969323/connecting-to-ibm-mq-using-ccdt-file-in-jms/58661300#58661300

Comment: Do you mean that after you have used the CCDT to make a connection, you want to be given as output, the values that were used from the chosen record?

Answer (score 2):

There is no MQ API or Class that will parse a CCDT file for an MQ application.

Set the environment variables MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB to point to where your CCDT file located and then use runmqsc with the '-n' parameter to have MQ manage it then issue the following MQSC command:

```
DIS CHL(*) ALL
```

Now you will have all of the details of all CLNTCONN channels from the CCDT file.

Comment: This was in my answer to the other question he linked to and on that question he said that is not what he is looking for :)

Comment: This was an eye-opener to me, thanks. Here is a oneliner: `echo 'DISPLAY CHANNEL(*) ALL' | MQCHLLIB=PATH_TO_CCDT_DIR MQCHLTAB=CCDT_FILENAME runmqsc -n`