# How to find the active host details using a Java client from IBM MQ's CCDT(Client Channel Definition Table) file?

Tags: ibm-mq, message-queue, mq

I have an IBM MQ's CCDT(Client Channel Definition Table) file (*.tab) which contains details about the Active host and the standby host. We are using this file to connect to the host. I would like to know which Host+port is currently active. Just to be displayed in the logs. Is there any utility class that can help me to find this information?

Note : I'm not trying to parse the CCDT file, rather extract the active host and port details from within a Java client after connecting to the host.

Comment: Duplicate question. Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662317/how-to-retrieve-the-connection-details-from-tab-file-mq/58662561#58662561

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the connection details From TAB file - MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662317/how-to-retrieve-the-connection-details-from-tab-file-mq)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have re framed the queston.

Comment: To know which port is active from ccdt file, you can write a program to pick each hostname from the ccdt file and check for that particular host the corresponding port mentioned in the CCDT is listening. For example, using command prompt one could do "telnet <<hostname>> <<port>>"