# JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN')

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I've tried to connect to ibm mq using ccdt. Below is my java code

```
private MQQueueConnectionFactory  connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    String cddtpath = "C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB";
    
    connectionFactory.setCCDTURL(new URL("file:///" + ccdtpath));
    connectionFactory.setQueueManager("MINE");
    queueConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection(username, pwd);
```

I've created SVRCONN as below:
`DEFINE CHANNEL(MINE.TCP.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) REPLACE` in my 20-config.mqsc file

and also I added corresponding CLNTCONN as below:

```
echo "DEFINE CHANNEL(MINE.TCP.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) QMNAME(MINE) CONNAME('localhost(9443)')" | MQCHLLIB=/tmp MQCHLTAB=AMQCLCHL.TAB runmqsc -n
```

as mentioned here [Connecting to IBM MQ using CCDT file in JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969323/connecting-to-ibm-mq-using-ccdt-file-in-jms/45971106#45971106)

after that I copied ccdt tab into local destination.

But I get an error: `JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').`

On docker I have latest (9 version) but in app I'm using 8.0 version.

What can be the reason?

After restart I can see below logs in ./mnt/mqm/data/errors/AMQERR01.LOG:

```
 07/03/20 07:54:59 - Process(108.3) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(b3316126fce2) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.5.0)
                    Time(2020-07-03T07:54:59.992Z)
                    ArithInsert1(108)
                    CommentInsert1(MINE)

AMQ6184W: An internal IBM MQ error has occurred on queue manager MINE.

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the IBM MQ error recording routine has been
called. The failing process is process 108.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved.
```

Full 2009 error:

```
<Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://MINE/MYQUEUE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MINE' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'file:/C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB', see linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').>


0001 CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:9443 (localhost)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=localhost/127.0.0.1:9443 (localhost),4=TCP] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException] 

[03/06/20 18:16:54.130.0K]  0001  @785fc51   c.i.m.j.remote.api.RemoteFAP                                           ----+----  !  jmqiConnect(String,JmqiConnectOptions,MQCNO,Hconn,Phconn,Pint,Pint,RemoteHconn)<throwIndex 20>, CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(9443)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'localhost/127.0.0.1:9443 (localhost)'. [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=localhost/127.0.0.1:9443 (localhost),4=TCP]],3=localhost(9443)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ,5=RemoteConnection.receiveTSH] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException]
```

Full 2278 error:

```
JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').>
:::::::----+-  {  reasonToException(int,String,String,String,String,HashMap<String , ? extends Object>) [2278(0x8e6)] [JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager '' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'file:/C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB', see linked exception for more information.] [JMSWMQ2020] <null> [Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.] [{XMSC_INSERT_QUEUE_MANAGER=, XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE=Client, XMSC_WMQ_CCDTURL=file:/C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB}]
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code where you set `ccdt`. We can't tell whether you are picking up the correct CCDTURL from the code you have posted.

Comment: I can not see any error there (./mnt/mqm/data/qmgrs/MINE/errors/AMQERR01.LOG and ./mnt/mqm/data/errors/AMQERR01.LOG)

Comment: I've added setting cddt.

Comment: After restart there are some logs, added to question description.

Comment: yes, 9443. Full stack is added into quest.

Comment: Can you add these java system properties to your java program and capture a MQ trace: `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=C:/tmp/jmstrace.txt`  Review this for the `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN` and post the trace around that point if possible it should show more details on what is causing the 2009.

Comment: About previous-nothing, only information about starting, action field is empty.

Comment: I've added  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON and  com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=C:/tmp/jmstrace.txt to application.properties but no new file in c:/tmp after start.

Comment: this app need server, and can not be run in this way

Comment: Then can you try to set it programmatically: `System.setProperty("com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status", "ON"); System.setProperty("com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName", "C:/tmp/jmstrace.txt");`

Comment: Ok, it works. I get now: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').>

Comment: why quemanager is empty?

Comment: previously I had  deep in code connectionFactory.setQueueManager("MINE") that causes the broken message I guess

Comment: with  connectionFactory.setQueueManager("*") I get  : 
"Failed to connect to queue manager '*' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL"

Comment: I think it is the format of your CCDT URL.  I think it should be `file://C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB`.

Comment: after that change I have error with parsing ccdt

Comment: 0004 CC=2;RC=2278;AMQ9516: File error occurred. [1=java.net.UnknownHostException[C],3=file://C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB] [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException] at:
[04/06/20 09:02:28.131.1A]  0004   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.internal.CCDT.parse(CCDT.java:343)

Comment: Yes I had that wrong, it should be `file:///C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB` which is the value you show is set in your code, but in the error it references it as `XMSC_WMQ_CCDTURL=file:/C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB`.  In the 2278 error, it mentions "Please see the linked exception for more information."  Do you have the rest of the details that include the linked exception either from the trace or by specifically printing the linked exception?  This IBM KC [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032290_.htm) has sample code showing how to print the linked exception.

Comment: still doesn't work: <Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://MINE/MYQUEUE' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MINE' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'file://C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB', see linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').>

Comment: [JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager 'MINE' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'file://C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB', see linked exception for more information.] [JMSWMQ2020] <null> [Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.] [{XMSC_INSERT_QUEUE_MANAGER=MINE, XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE=Client, XMSC_WMQ_CCDTURL=file://C:/tmp/AMQCLCHL.TAB}]

Comment: Find the linked exception.

Comment: Did you get the Linked exception?

Comment: Yes, I had bad port, not 9443, but 1414 is correct.

Comment: In what way in this ccdt configuration failover is working? There is only one host.

Comment: I asked you on July 3rd to confirm 9443 wasn't the web console port, seemed wrong to me then,  443 is the normal https port and IBM MQ tends to use 9443 for the web console. If you only have 1 host there is no fail over unless you consider docker bringing the QM back up.  If you have reconnect enabled it will at least reconnect to itself when it is available again within the reconnect timeout.

Comment: Not sure why your error changed from 2009 to 2278?  Is it possible originally 9443 was not up or not available (first error stack references connection refused) and this is when you got 2009, later 9443 was running but because it was not the MQ port that it changed to 2278?